# A second call to setVisibility has no effect

Tags: java, android, visibility

I am writing an android game. A `LinearLayout` will show initially and after the game finishes. The user can tap on the `LinearLayout` to start the game and the `LinearLayout` disappears (`setVisibility (View.GONE)`) with an animation.

After the game has finished, the same `LinearLayout` shows up with another animation. This time I call `setVisibility (View.Visible)` in the `onAnimationStart` method. However, after the game ends, I can't see neither the animation nor the `LinearLayout`.

Here's my code:

```
public void removeCover (View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this, R.anim.cover_move_out);
    anim.setAnimationListener (new Animation.AnimationListener () {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            GameActivity.this.cover.setVisibility (View.GONE);
            Game.getInstance ().startGame ();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    cover.startAnimation (anim);
}

public void gameOver () {
    tvScore.setText (Integer.toString (Game.getInstance ().getScore ()));
    tvScoreText.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    tvScore.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this, R.anim.cover_fade_in);
    anim.setAnimationListener (new Animation.AnimationListener () {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            GameActivity.this.cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            GameActivity.this.cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
            Game.InitializeGame (GameActivity.this);
            cover.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

cover_move_out Animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="100%"
        android:fromYScale="100%"
        android:toXScale="0%"
        android:toYScale="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

cover_fade_in Animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Explanation:
`removeCover` will be called when the user taps on the `LinearLayout`. `gameOver` will be called when the game ends. I tried putting `setVisibility(View.Visible)` in various places: in the `gameOver` method, in the `onAnimationEnds` and `onAnimationStarts` method. I also tried to set the visibility to `INVISIBLE` before the animation starts. But none of that works. I think it might be because `setVisibility(View.GONE)` can only be called once. And after that the view is really "GONE".

Comment: You need to call cover.startAnimation (anim) in gameOver () too , like in removeCover()

Comment: Oh shoot! Silly me! Thanks!